# hbase installation on single node

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i have installed hadoop single node on ubuntu 12.04. Now I am trying to install hbase over it (version 0.94.18). But i get the following errors(even though i have extracted it in the /usr/local/hbase):

```
    Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool
    Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
    starting master, logging to /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/logs/hbase-hduser-master-ubuntu.out
    nice: /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/bin/hbase: No such file or directory
    cat: /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/conf/regionservers: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You downloaded src version instead of binary version.

Answer (score 5):

To resolve This Error

1. Download binary version of hbase
2. Edit conf file hbase-env.sh and hbase-site.xml
3. Set Up Hbase Home Directory
4. Start hbase By - Start-hbase.sh

Explanation To above Error:

> Could not find or load main class your downloaded version does not have required jar

Comment: Download *binary version* of hbase, this is the main point, I was trying to run hbase using the source and was getting this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111562/error-running-pseudo-distributed-hbase 

This solved things as well if others have installed via `brew install hbase` like myself too.

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you tell when it is coming this error.
I think you gave environment set wrong
You should enter bellow command:

export HBASE_HOME="/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.18"

Then try hbase it will work.
If you want shell script you can download this lik :: https://github.com/tonyreddy/Apache-Hadoop1.2.1-SingleNode-installation-shellscript
It have hadoop, hive, hbase, pig.

Thank
Tony.

Comment: when i give the command "bin/start-hbase.sh" this error comes.

Comment: should i make this change in hbase-env.sh or hbase-site.xml? I am a pretty confused about this.

Comment: Yes there you gave /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8, it should be /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.18.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/<\/configuration>/<property>\n<name>hbase.rootdir<\/name>\n<value>hdfs:\/\/'$c':54310\/hbase<\/value>\n<\/property>\n<property>\n<name>hbase.cluster.distributed<\/name>\n<value>true<\/value>\n<\/property>\n<property>\n<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort<\/name>\n<value>2181<\/value>\n<\/property>\n<property>\n<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum<\/name>\n<value>'$c'<\/value>\n<\/property>\n<\/configuration>/g" -i.bak hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml

sed 's/localhost/'$c'/g' hbase/conf/regionservers -i

sed 's/#\ export\ HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true/export\ HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true/g' hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh -i
```

Yes just type this tree commands and you need change replace $c to your hostname.
Then try it will work.

Comment: It would have been a lot more helpful if you had written out and explained what changes these sed commands are making.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to run hbase from the source distribution directly instead you have to download the binary distribution as they have mentioned in [their official site](http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html), follow the same instructions and you will get it up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the version 0.94.27

Download it from : [h-base 0.94.27 dowload](http://mirror.fibergrid.in/apache/hbase/hbase-0.94.27/hbase-0.94.27.tar.gz)
This one worked for me.

Follow the instruction specified in :
[Hbase installation guide](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/quickstart.html)