# Error running pseudo-distributed hbase

Tags: macos, hadoop, hbase

I installed Hadoop and HBase in Mac OSX 10.9 through Homebrew. The version of Hadoop is 2.5.1, and the version of HBase is 0.98.6.1.

After I started HDFS, and try to start HBase, I got these errors:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
>
> starting master, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hbase/0.98.6.1/logs/hbase-lsphate-master-Ethans-MacBook-Pro.local.out
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
>
> localhost: starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hbase/0.98.6.1/logs/hbase-lsphate-regionserver-Ethans-MacBook-Pro.local.out
>
> localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer

Is there any suggestion of this error? I've googled it and tried any solution I can find but they were all no use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your's HBASE_HOME might not be pointing to the correct location. Try exporting HBASE_HOME and HBASE_CONF_DIR like

export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hbase/0.98.6.1/libexec 
export HBASE_CONF_DIR=$HBASE_HOME/conf

Thanks.

Comment: ah! need the extra `/libexec` nice catch!